# Java API - List<int[]> to JSON error

Tags: java, json, rest, jax-rs

My REST API should return a list of objects

```
public List<MyObject> getMyObjects() { ... }
```

**MyObject**

```
public class MyObject {

    private int id;
    private String name;
    private List<int[]> coordinates;

    // getters
    // setters
}
```

The call on this method works and there is no error.

The problem is about list of coordinates. When generating the JSON my list of int[] is transformed into this

```
"coordinates":["[I@409cd27c","[I@1a552b8c","[I@1af3f13d","[I@5e12856b","[I@78bba3e7", //...
```

How can I make the JSON transformation work with this list ? Everything is working fine with other variable.

Comment: What is the content's of these `int[]`'s? What Json library are you using?

Comment: I am using `genson-1.4` and tis list contains multiple [x,y] that are coordinates points

Comment: You shouldn't use an `int[]` anyway. Create a proper model class which will represent a coordinate where you also check if the values are valid. You `int[]` can be empty or contains "a lot" of values and both cases aren't valid, right?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're getting, exactly as expected, the `toString()` of those `int[]`s. Ideally, you should encapsulate the bare coordinate pairs into a `Point` class, but if that's not practical because of other requirements about the JSON, use a list instead of an array:

```
List<List<Integer>> coordinates;
```